# mod_rewrite Redirect to specific URL if domain X is used?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site with two domains. I want that whenever domain X is visited (no matter what the path is... /foo/bar/, root or whatever), the browser should redirect to a specific URL.

So:

```
domainX.com -> domainX.com
domainY.com -> domainX.com/some/path
```

The following kinda sorta works, but it only matches against `domainY.com`, so `www.domainY.com` or `domainY.com/some/path` doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainY\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainX\.com/some/path [L]
```

It has to accept both with and without www before though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend the regular expression for `HTTP_HOST`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainY\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://domainX.com/some/path [L]
```

This is a rewrite. If you want to redirect the client, you must add an [`R`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule .* http://domainX.com/some/path [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: Now www also works, but if i put something after the domain (ex `domainY.com/some/path` it doesn't work. That's not as important though, i can live without it. Thank you!

Comment: @qwerty This is strange, it should work with or without an additional URL-path. Do you have additional rules? Or do you get some error message?

Comment: I do have additional rules. They were in the OP but i edited them out because i thought it was irrelevant. See here: http://pastebin.com/Xh0u1AsA Now that i think about it, i should also probably put my rules within the <if>. Could the other rules cause it to not work?